# How do I regain Arcane Power effectively with my Frozen Orb Wizard?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

I'm mainly using a Frozen Orb/Electrocute Wizard at the moment. It works pretty well, but I run out of AP very often. Until recently this wasn't bad enough to actually do much about it, I was somewhat resource-constrained, but I could still regain the AP with Electrocute pretty quickly.

The latest patch changed this, now it takes a lot longer to fill up my AP globe by electrocuting enemies. So I'll have to start looking for ways to gain more AP now to fix this problem, and I'm wondering which methods are effective for my build.

I'm currently using the following AP regeneration methods:

- Electrocute with Surge of Power and the Prodigy passive
- 3 AP per critical hit on my helmet

My subjective impression is that the APoC didn't do anything useful. I have a 54% critical hit chance, but it doesn't seem to affect my AP very much.

What are effective ways to regenerate AP for a Frozen Orb Wizard?

Comment: I don't play a wizard, but I'm pretty sure APoC is the way to go. The problem you're running into is that blizzard nerfed the proc coefficient for Electrocute from 0.25 to 0.167 (I think), which is a huge nerf.  You may need to either get more APoC or use another signature spell.

Comment: you'll need a combination of apoc and cost reduction.  The decreased AOE has made it super hard to cast as many forbs as before.

Comment: Maximize your apoc and attack speed. More tick > more crit > more AP. Prodigy seems mandatory and will regenerate more AP if your attack speed is higher. Frozen orb was ridiculously broken and Wiz will have to learn how to position better in order to maximize their damage and AP regeneration. You can no longer waste FO on trash but you can do like DH : when entering an area, gather the mob and wait a a big stack to maximize your Damage per Arcane Power spent. Also the Frozen orb/electrocute built was killing the diversity and maybe its time for a build change and try new things with the Wiz

Comment: I can't think of any build that can afford to leave out Prodigy, so I say this is basically the bread and butter of regaining AP for a mage.

Answer (score 1):

I used to be a frozen orb wizard and I know where you are coming from, I also have 50%+ CC, 8 APoC, Prodigy, Electrocute (Surge of Power) and also Myken's Ball of Hate source, which let's the  electrocute jump to more enemies (so more AP regen), I have more arcane power regeneration that you, even after that I run out of AP pretty fast.

Like Divinicus has pointed out, Reaper's Wraps helps a lot (recently crafted this), so does having more Max AP. Another good thing is having a good Resource Cost Reduction. I once tested a setup with 30%+ resource cost reduction with gears and paragon points + Storm armor (Power of the Storm), that was pretty effective. It was not as effective as the pre-RoS 30 APoC setup I had, but I'd say it'd be identical to 20-24 APoC build. But I had to abandon the setup as I got a few upgraded legendaries and they didn't roll with RCR.

I've been steadily moving to a fire build since, with Cindercoat + Pride's fall, you can easily end up with 50% resource cost reduction, the toughest part is getting those two armor pieces :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use the unique item "Reaper's Wraps"?

Frozen Orb consume AP so quickly that it won't be enough, but it's still quite a lot of bonus AP regen.
In multiplayer, allies who pick up near globes will give you AP back too.
And the higher the max AP, the more effective the item will be (try to combine it with Energy armor-Energy Tap if you really need AP and your build allows it).
You can also try the absorption or pinpoint barrier (for APoC) rune on Energy Armor.